# random domains get parked on my server

Tags: nginx, dns

I was looking through my nginx error log and found strange records

```
2014/10/01 13:41:20 [error] 9825#0: *1628 "/home/mysite/public_html/phone/99476982139/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 37.187.107.37, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /phone/99476982139/ HTTP/1.1", host: "blabla.co.uk"

2014/10/01 13:41:22 [error] 9825#0: *1629 "/home/mysite/public_html/phone/99476982139/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 180.76.5.145, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /phone/99476982139/ HTTP/1.1", host: "blabla.com.ar"
```

But what happened next was astonishing - I visited those strange domains - blabla.co.uk and blabla.com.ar, and they have THE SAME CONTENT AS MY mysite.com!!! If I change my index.html file, content is changed on those domains which I see for the fist time in my life!

My nginx config for this site is quite simple

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    root /home/mysite/public_html;
}
```

How can that happen?
How can I protect my server from requests to random domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the domains just point to the IP of your server.

In order to protect yourself from this kind of thing, simply add a default server block in your config. All requests not explicitly pointed at your domain are sent to the default server and will eventually drop.. Here's a quick example:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
  root /home/mysite/public_html;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /var/www/dead; 
}
```

'dead' is some empty folder.. you might also wanna try adding a `deny all;` to the default server block.